# How to Export Cycles Rendered object for Three.js

Tags: cycles-render-engine, three.js

I have created a model that I want to use in my THREE.js web application. However, I can only get it work when I export the Blender file while using the Blender Renderer. Does anyone know how to successfully export with the Cycles Renderer to JSON for THREE.js?

Answer (score 1):

The three.js exporter [doesn't support Cycles nodes](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12344). You may want to try exporting to [other formats that three.js supports](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/loaders). The best supported are currently FBX and [glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter).

Comment: You can bake the materials used in cycles into an image, and such image then mapped on exported objects.